# How to start rails server command as daemon that relaunch after reboot or crush?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx

I setup Nginx for listening to lockalhost:3000 than I launch rails command `bundle exec rails server webrick -e production`. I found that I can launch rails server as daemon simply adds the -d flag to the command, so the command becomes a `bundle exec rails server -d  webrick -e production`. My problem is that after server reloads or app is crushed - that a dead-end, I can't found info about how should I create "rails as a daemon with auto relaunch".

Comment: Use monit ? https://mmonit.com/monit/ to monitor the process and relaunch if killed ?

Answer (score 0):

`webrick` in production?

Please please please refrain from doing anything like that. Use `puma` or `unicorn` or any similar app server for your purpose.

And for the process monitoring part, you can use `systemd`, or `monit` for better control.

Personally, I prefer `monit` as it gives me crash logs and downtime alerts.